# moviepy black border around png when compositing into an MP4

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

compositing a png into an MP4 video creates a black border around the edge.

This is using moviepy 1.0.0

Code below reproduces the MP4 with the attached red text png.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import moviepy.editor as mped
def composite_txtpng_on_colour():
    bg_color = mped.ColorClip(size=[400, 300], color=np.array([0, 255, 0]).astype(np.uint8),
                          duration=2).set_position((0, 0))
    text_png_postition = [5, 5]
    text_png = mped.ImageClip("./txtpng.png", duration=3).set_position((text_png_postition))

    canvas_size = bg_color.size
    stacked_clips = mped.CompositeVideoClip([bg_color, text_png], size=canvas_size).set_duration(2)
    stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.mp4', fps=24)

composite_txtpng_on_colour()
```

The result is an MP4 that can be played in VLC player.  A screenshot of the black edge can be seen below:-

[image]

Any suggestions to remove the black borders would be much appreciated.

Update:  It looks like moviepy does a blit instead of alpha compositing.

```
def blit(im1, im2, pos=None, mask=None, ismask=False):
    """ Blit an image over another.  Blits ``im1`` on ``im2`` as position ``pos=(x,y)``, using the
    ``mask`` if provided. If ``im1`` and ``im2`` are mask pictures
    (2D float arrays) then ``ismask`` must be ``True``.
    """
    if pos is None:
        pos = [0, 0]

    # xp1,yp1,xp2,yp2 = blit area on im2
    # x1,y1,x2,y2 = area of im1 to blit on im2
    xp, yp = pos
    x1 = max(0, -xp)
    y1 = max(0, -yp)
    h1, w1 = im1.shape[:2]
    h2, w2 = im2.shape[:2]
    xp2 = min(w2, xp + w1)
    yp2 = min(h2, yp + h1)
    x2 = min(w1, w2 - xp)
    y2 = min(h1, h2 - yp)
    xp1 = max(0, xp)
    yp1 = max(0, yp)

    if (xp1 >= xp2) or (yp1 >= yp2):
        return im2

    blitted = im1[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    new_im2 = +im2

    if mask is None:
        new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2] = blitted
    else:
        mask = mask[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        if len(im1.shape) == 3:
            mask = np.dstack(3 * [mask])
        blit_region = new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2]
        new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2] = (1.0 * mask * blitted + (1.0 - mask) * blit_region)
    
    return new_im2.astype('uint8') if (not ismask) else new_im2
```

and so, Rotem is right.

```
new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2] = (1.0 * mask * blitted + (1.0 - mask) * blit_region)
```

is

```
(alpha * img_rgb + (1.0 - alpha) * bg)
```

and this is how moviepy composites.  And this is why we see black at the edges.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is the [YUV420](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion) color sub-sumpling, but it's also a result of compression artifacts, and imperfect "Text red" image.

The image imperfection is just in the alpha channel.
There are alpha (transparency) values that are not 255 and not 0 (semi-transparnt) pixels around the text.

The following code sample corrects it, and show the difference (using OpenCV):

```
orig_img = cv2.imread('txtpng.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = orig_img.copy()
img[(img != 255) & (img != 0)] = 255  # Keep only two values: 0 and 255
cv2.imwrite('txtpng2.png', img)  # Write img to txtpng2.png
cv2.imshow('alpha diff', cv2.absdiff(orig_img[:,:,3], img[:,:,3])*100) # Show the difference in alpha channels
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code keeps only two values: 0 and 255 in `img`.

Result ('alpha diff'):
[image]
As you can see there are differences.

---

Setting codec parameters:

For reference I created an uncompressed AVI video file:

```
# Save uncompressed AVI as reference
stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.avi', fps=24, codec='rawvideo', ffmpeg_params=['-pix_fmt', 'bgr24'])
```

I also tried to select H.264 codec with `yuv444p` pixel format, but for some reason it's not working.
I have selected H.265 codec instead.
Using `ffmpeg_params`, I also set `'-crf', '10'` for almost lossless video compression:

```
stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.mp4', fps=24, codec='libx265', ffmpeg_params=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv444p', '-crf', '10'])
```

---

Here is the complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import moviepy.editor as mped
import cv2

orig_img = cv2.imread('txtpng.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = orig_img.copy()
img[(img != 255) & (img != 0)] = 255  # Keep only two values: 0 and 255
cv2.imwrite('txtpng2.png', img)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('alpha diff', cv2.absdiff(orig_img[:,:,3], img[:,:,3])*100) # Show the difference in alpha channels
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def composite_txtpng_on_colour():
    bg_color = mped.ColorClip(size=[400, 300], color=np.array([0, 255, 0]).astype(np.uint8),
                          duration=2).set_position((0, 0))
    text_png_postition = [5, 5]
    text_png = mped.ImageClip('txtpng2.png', duration=3).set_position((text_png_postition))

    canvas_size = bg_color.size
    stacked_clips = mped.CompositeVideoClip([bg_color, text_png], size=canvas_size).set_duration(2)
    stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.mp4', fps=24, codec='libx265', ffmpeg_params=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv444p', '-crf', '10'])

    # Save uncompressed AVI as reference
    stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.avi', fps=24, codec='rawvideo', ffmpeg_params=['-pix_fmt', 'bgr24'])

composite_txtpng_on_colour()
```

---

Result (`text_with_black_border_video.mp4`):
[image]

Reference (uncompressed `text_with_black_border_video.avi`):
[image]

Magnified part:
[image]

---

Note:

- I am using moviepy version 1.03

---

I figured out why H.264 codec is not working with pixel format `yuv444p`.

We can add `'-report'` to the list of `ffmpeg_params`:

```
stacked_clips.write_videofile('text_with_black_border_video.mp4', fps=24, codec='libx264', ffmpeg_params=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv444p', '-crf', '10', '-report'])
```

The logged report begins with:

`... \\lib\\site-packages\\imageio_ffmpeg\\binaries\\ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe" -y -loglevel error -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 400x300 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 24.00 -an -i - -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 10 -report -pix_fmt yuv420p text_with_black_border_video.mp4`

The log shows that moviepy added `-pix_fmt yuv420p` argument.
`pix_fmt` argument is added twice: `-pix_fmt yuv444p` `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.
The `yuv420p` argument "wins".

---

### Update:

**Way to keep the edges slightly blurred:**

The edges color is not back, but dark green.
The edges color is a result of [Alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) in RGB color space.
I suppose the compositing is performed using the simple formula:

`dst_img = alpha*img_rgb + (1-alpha)*bg`
Where `alpha = img[:,:,0:3]/255`.

When applying the above formula we are getting the following image:

[image]
Text edge color is dark green.

Suggested solution:
Apply alpha compositing in [LAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space.

Advantage:

> Unlike the RGB and CMYK color models, CIELAB is designed to approximate human vision.

Linear operations in LAB color space are precepted as (approximate) linear by human vision.

Here is a code sample for alpha compositing in LAB color space:

```
img = cv2.imread('txtpng.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = np.zeros((300, 400, 4), np.uint8)
img2[(300-img.shape[0])//2:(300+img.shape[0])//2, (400-img.shape[1])//2:(400+img.shape[1])//2, :] = img
alpha = img2[:, :, 3].astype(np.float64)/255  # Convert alpha to range [0, 1]
alpha = np.dstack((alpha, alpha, alpha))  # Duplicate alpha to 3 channels
img2 = img2[:, :, 0:3]  # Only BGR without alpha

bg = np.full_like(img2, (0, 255, 0)) # Green background

bg = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
composed_img = (img2.astype(np.float64)*alpha + bg.astype(np.float64)*(1-alpha)).astype(np.uint8)
composed_img = cv2.cvtColor(composed_img, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

cv2.imwrite('composed_img.png', composed_img) # Store the result
```

Result:
[image]
Text edge color looks better.

Note:
I couldn't find any papers about alpha compositing in LAB color space (but I didn't look so hard).

Comment: That's great.  Thank you Rotem.  Grateful for your response.  Is there any way to keep the edges slightly blurred / smooth without getting a black edge ?

Comment: I tried alpha compositing in LAB color space, and it looks better. You may look for papers of improving the perceptual result of alpha compositing.

Comment: I just looked, and it looks like moviepy does a blit, so no alpha compositing.  I just updated the post with the blit code.

Comment: Thanks again Rotem for this LAB color space approach.  Looks really great.  Wondering now how to get the LAB result you have, and still use moviepy to composite.  So I can composite with other moviepy objects.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't  use MoviePy to composite in LAB color space, but you can compose the frames using OpenCV and NumPy, and encode the composed frames video using MoviePy.

Comment: Rotem, do you know how FFMPEG Overlay in filter-complex combines two images ?

Comment: I don't know the specific algorithm. I tested it with your red text on a green background, and the artifacts looks worst than MoviePy.

Comment: Thank you Rotem,
please could you explain the formula you posted? :-

dst_img = alpha*img_rgb + (1-alpha)*bg

so for example, if I have three pixels like this
alpha = [[255,255,255], [127, 127, 127], [0,0,0]]
rgb_image = [[255,255,255], [0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
bg = [[0,255,0],[0,255,0],[0,255,0]]
how would the result of this be with that blit formula ?

Comment: **1.** Convert all to float (to `np.float64`), **2.** Divide alpha by 255, so the range is [0, 1]. **3.** Compute `dst_img = alpha*img_rgb + (1-alpha)*bg`. **4.** Convert the result to type `np.uint8`. `alpha*x` + (1-alpha)*y` is a "weighted sum" of `x` and `y`. (when `alpha` range is 0 to 1). What is the Alpha compositing [formula](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/540bc19312e7e8f6fae83985f7f2cca7f6b2c504) in Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use on_color to make a background color for your CompositeVideoClip, or else, edges will be black. Use this helper function to generate a color clip instead:

```
def get_color_video_clip(color, size, duration):
    image = Image.new("RGB", size, color)
    image_array = numpy.array(image)

    return mpy.ImageClip(image_array, duration=duration)
```

Also, as a sanity check, play the video back in different media players. On Mac, IINA made edges gray for me, while QuickTime Player had no such issues.