# Blending images without color change?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors, contrast

While studying OpenCV, I realized that whenever I blend two images the colors of scr2 have changed in some way(depends on the colors of scr1).

I know this is not an informative and clear way to explain my issue, however; I don't know how to describe this issue since I have no expertise with colors so I would like to show you what I meant with images and code.

The input image: [Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB4D7.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("inputImage.png")

scr2=255*np.ones((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3),dtype=np.uint8)


#adding lines 

cv2.line(scr2,(100,0),(100,img.shape[1]),(0,255,0),3) 
cv2.line(scr2,(300,0),(300,img.shape[1]),(255,0,0),3)
cv2.line(scr2,(500,0),(500,img.shape[1]),(0,0,255),3)

#blending

blend=cv2.addWeighted(img,0.7,scr2,0.3,0)
crop=blend[60:100,460:530]

cv2.imwrite("crop.png",crop)

cv2.imwrite("line.png",blend)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Sb9.png)

[cropped in red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrS9F.png)
As you can see, even though I added a single color for each line, the colors of lines have changed depends on the background color. The red line does not seem to be red in the cropped image.

Can you elaborate on why this happening and how can I avoid this problem? I mean, I don't want the color change on lines.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Blending of two color images is a mixing of colors since it is taking a weighted average of the two colors. When you overlay two partially transparent colors, they blend or mix colors since you can see one behind the other. Using weighting of two opaque colors is like putting the weight as the transparency. The only way to preserve colors is to set the weight of the lines to 1 (and the background to one) so that they are effectively totally opaque when placing over the image. In other words, just draw your lines directly on your background image without addWeighted.

Comment: @fmw42 I see, thank you for this informative reply. But If I add lines directly into the target image; a lot of information also gone(because of overlaying). So, is it impossible to blend images while preserveing actual colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the blend to resembled perceptual color blending (closer to the expected blend color by humans), you may apply the blending in [LAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space.

Advantage:

> Unlike the RGB and CMYK color models, CIELAB is designed to approximate human vision.

I have demonstrated the principal in my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67924185/4926757) (at the bottom).

- Convert `img` and `scr2` from BGR to LAB color space.
- Apply `addWeighted` in LAB color space.
- Convert the result from LAB to BGR color space.

Since the blending of white background of `scr2` bothers me, I also copy the original pixels from `img` to `blend` where pixels in `scr2` are white.

---

Here is a complete code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("inputImage.png")

scr2 = np.full_like(img, 255)

img_lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # Convert color space from BGR to LAB color space

# adding lines
cv2.line(scr2, (100, 0), (100, img.shape[1]), (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.line(scr2, (300, 0), (300, img.shape[1]), (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.line(scr2, (500, 0), (500, img.shape[1]), (0, 0, 255), 3)

scr2_lab = cv2.cvtColor(scr2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # Convert color space from BGR to LAB color space

# blending
#blend = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.7, scr2, 0.3, 0)
blend_lab = cv2.addWeighted(img_lab, 0.7, scr2_lab, 0.3, 0)  # Blend images in LAB color space
blend = cv2.cvtColor(blend_lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # Convert color space from LAB to BGR color space

# Replace blended "background" white pixels of scr2 with original pixel values from img:
mask = np.all(scr2 == 255, 2).astype(np.uint8)  # Mask value is 1 where 3 color channels are 255
cv2.copyTo(img, mask, blend)  # Copy pixels from img to blend where mask != 0.


crop = blend[60:100, 460:530]

cv2.imwrite("crop2.png", crop)
cv2.imwrite("line2.png", blend)

# Show the results
cv2.imshow('mask', mask*255)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('blend', blend)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
left: `crop` blended in LAB space.
right: `crop` blended in BGR space.
[image] [image]

Note:

- It's more accurate but doesn't look very helpful in this case...

---

**Copy the luminance from `src2` to `blend`**:

According to your comment, it looks like you want to keep the luminance of the colored lines from `src2`, and not blend the luminance with the background.

In LAB color space, the L color channel is the luminance.

You may copy the luminance from `src2` to `blend` where `src2` is not white.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

blend_lab = cv2.addWeighted(img_lab, 0.7, scr2_lab, 0.3, 0)  # Blend images in LAB color space

```
# Get the luminance channel (get NumPy slice)
scr2_luminance = scr2_lab[:, :, 0]
blend_luminance = blend_lab[:, :, 0]
blend_luminance[np.any(scr2 != 255, 2)] = scr2_luminance[np.any(scr2 != 255, 2)]  # Copy the luminace from scr2_lab to blend_lab where scr2 is not white.

blend = cv2.cvtColor(blend_lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # Convert color space from LAB to BGR color space
```

---

Result:
`crop`:
[image]

`blend`:
[image]

Note:

- The luminance looks correct, but we are loosing the color saturation.

We may copy the saturation channel from `scr2` to `blend` in HSV color space:

```
scr2_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(scr2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
blend_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blend, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
blend_hsv[:,:,1][np.any(scr2 != 255, 2)] = scr2_hsv[:,:,1][np.any(scr2 != 255, 2)]  # Copy the saturation channel.
blend = cv2.cvtColor(blend_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

I am not sure that it makes sense...

Comment: Very informative answer. Thank you so much for your attention. It seems I can solve those "perceived colors in human vision" problems with LAB or HSV colorspace.

Answer (score 3):

I think I misunderstood your issue. If your issue is that the image where you do not have lines has changed, then that is because you used a white background for scr2. The white then mixes with your image in the output. Make it scr2=img.copy() in place of what you have now. Then try your code. So in Python/OpenCV as a demonstration, using the Lena image as background, here is your code:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("lena.png")

scr2=255*np.ones((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3),dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.line(scr2,(50,0),(50,img.shape[1]),(0,255,0),13) 
cv2.line(scr2,(100,0),(100,img.shape[1]),(255,0,0),13)
cv2.line(scr2,(150,0),(150,img.shape[1]),(0,0,255),13)

blend=cv2.addWeighted(img,0.7,scr2,0.3,0)

cv2.imwrite("line.png",blend)
```

You can now see that the background has white mixed with it.

[image]

However, if we use the input image for scr2,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("lena.png")

scr2=img.copy()

cv2.line(scr2,(50,0),(50,img.shape[1]),(0,255,0),13) 
cv2.line(scr2,(100,0),(100,img.shape[1]),(255,0,0),13)
cv2.line(scr2,(150,0),(150,img.shape[1]),(0,0,255),13)

blend=cv2.addWeighted(img,0.7,scr2,0.3,0)

cv2.imwrite("line.png",blend)
```

then we get:

[image]

which has preserved the background color.

Comment: Thank you so much! It giving much more good results! However, unfortunately still have some little issues with my original input image.
Here is the result in my original input instead of Lena (with your code):
https://ibb.co/9tbnv31 (cropped for green line)

As you can see, the "luminance of greenline (not sure whether this term is true) " is changing depending on the background color.

Comment: That is the issue I mentioned originally. addWeighted of two colors changes the appearance because it mixes the two colors. So green over black mixes green with black to darken the green. Whereas, green over pink mixes the two creating a pinkish-green color.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your attention and time! I will look more deeply.